How Can I Customize the Background Color and Other Properties of UITextField Inside a UISearchBar?
I’m trying to customize the appearance of a UITextField inside a UISearchBar. Specifically, I want to change the background color and other style properties. I am using the following code to make some adjustments
func configureMarkerSearchBar(with placeholder: String) {
backgroundColor = .clear
tintColor = .clear
searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(SearchBarConstants.searchBarLayerRadius)
searchTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
sizeToFit()

if let textField = value(forKey: SearchBarConstants.searchFieldKey) as? UITextField {
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder,
                                              attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:
                                                  SearchBarConstants.searchBarTextInputColor])
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
    textField.font = UIFont.regularDMSans(of: SearchBarConstants.textFieldFontSize)
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = SearchBarConstants.searchBarCornerRadius
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.backgroundColor = .clear
    textField.tintColor = .clear
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(46)),
        textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
    ])
    searchTextField.clipsToBounds = true
    
    if let searchIcon = UIImage(named: SearchBarConstants.iconSearch) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: searchIcon)
        searchIcon.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        searchIcon.withTintColor(SearchBarConstants.searchBarTextInputColor)
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                               width: SearchBarConstants.searchIconOffset + searchIcon.size.width,
                                               height: searchIcon.size.height))
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: SearchBarConstants.searchIconOffset, y: 0,
                                 width: searchIcon.size.width,
                                 height: searchIcon.size.height)
        paddingView.addSubview(imageView)
        textField.leftView = paddingView
        textField.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}

}
The issue I’m facing is that whenever I try to access and modify the background view of the UITextField, it always defaults to tertiarySystemFillColor instead of the custom color I set.
Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I successfully change the background color and ensure my customizations are applied properly?
Thank you!
View Hierarchy
Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I successfully change the background color and ensure my customizations are applied properly?

You can modify text field directly through searchTextField property of UISearchBar.
Example UIViewController to demonstrate customization of text field.
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - UISearchController
    lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
        let view = UISearchBar()
        view.placeholder = "Search here..."
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        setupSearchBar()
        customizeSearchBar()
    }
    
    private func setupSearchBar() {
        view.addSubview(searchBar)
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    private func customizeSearchBar() {
        searchBar.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill"), for: .search, state: .normal)
        searchBar.searchTextField.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        searchBar.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none
        searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .red
        searchBar.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0
    }
}

Result:

